# A curve that starts with exponential growth and levels out

Tags: functions

I'm stuck on a mathematical problem in a small feature I'm building for a website. I need a function that starts out with exponential growth and than levels out as x grows. I've drawn this wonderful picture to communicate what I'm looking for since my math lingo isn't the best.

Any help appreciated.

[image: curve]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you want a [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem :)

Comment: Use these all the time for programming, easiest to use are logistic and `atan`

Comment: You say "starts out with exponential growth", so you want the logistic function.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for something like ${\rm erf}(x-2)+1$, where erf is the error function, ${\rm erf}(x) = \frac{2}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_0^x {e^{ - t^2 } dt} $. You can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/gallery/view.jsp?id=97f58cc60361f36cb40942c5c9a9e029) to watch the graph: plot $f(x)={\rm erf}(x-2)+1$, say from $0$ to $5$. Further see Wikipedia's plot of the error function, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), to understand the reason for choosing ${\rm erf}(x-2)+1$.